# Cant find File System, Registry icon in WIX setup project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix

[image]

I installed WIX in my machine.
I followed the video of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoFPyIbcqN8[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoFPyIbcqN8)

I can not find any way to add File Systems, no icon for it, no context menu entry on project.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the Add-In Express designer for WiX in the video. It's a paid for component.

Installing WiX on your system only adds project templates to Visual Studio. It's a free installer/packaging engine that uses XML (scripting) to build MSI's and etc and doesn't come with a designer.

WiX is quite a steep learning curve, if you want the editor then I suggest you check out the Package & Deployment add-in Microsoft re-introduced for VS2013, it's on VisualStudio Gallery. Brian Harry blogs about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/18/creating-installers-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it's not in VS2012 :( MS discontinued it after VS2010 and as Brian explains in his blog MS brought it back due to public outcry. There is an InstallShield 'basic' setup project in VS2012 that should do the trick. It will save you from either purchasing the ADX WiX designer or spending days/weeks learning how to script WiX.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 has a free Community Edition that you can use. You add the Installer add-on:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Then what you have is the same Visual Studio installer setup projects as you had in VS 2010.